# Java how to parse this timestamp "20200926T221447Z"

Tags: java, date, datetime

Things I've tried

```
  public class Event {

  private SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMddTHHmmssZ");
  
  private Date date;
  private String summary;
  
  public Date getDate() {
    return date;
  }
  
  public void setDate(Date date) {
    this.date = date;
  }
  
  public void setDate(String stringDate) throws ParseException {
    this.date = formatter.parse(stringDate);
  }
  
  public String getSummary() {
    return summary;
  }
  
  public void setSummary(String summary) {
    this.summary = summary;
  }
}
```

// main

```
String x = "20200926T221447Z"
Event event = new Event();
event.setDate(x);
```

**Exception I get**

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Illegal pattern character 'T'
    at java.text.SimpleDateFormat.compile(SimpleDateFormat.java:826)
    at java.text.SimpleDateFormat.initialize(SimpleDateFormat.java:634)
    at java.text.SimpleDateFormat.<init>(SimpleDateFormat.java:605)
    at java.text.SimpleDateFormat.<init>(SimpleDateFormat.java:580)
    at stuff.calendar.Event.<init>(Event.java:9)
    at stuff.calendar.App.main(App.java:34)
```

**Question :** Is my SimpleDateFormat incorrect? I've tried changing this around but none work. Is there another java API I should use to parse this particular time format?

Comment: You should be using the classes from the `java.time` package.  `Date` is obsolete and most of its ilk are deprecated.

Comment: *Is there another java API I should use to parse this particular time format?* There certainly is, and all other formats too. @WJS said it already: [java.time, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When attempting to parse a `String` into a date-time object, I tend to prefer using a [`DateTimeFormatter`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/15/docs/api/java.base/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html) over [`SimpleDateFormat`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/15/docs/api/java.base/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

I was able to parse your `String` into a [`ZonedDateTime`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/15/docs/api/java.base/java/time/ZonedDateTime.html) object with the following snippet:

```
String x = "20200926T221447Z";
DateTimeFormatter dtf = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("uuuuMMdd'T'HHmmssX");
System.out.println(ZonedDateTime.parse(x, dtf));
```

Output:

```
2020-09-26T22:14:47Z
```

Comment: @Java4Life you should accept this answer if it meets your requirements.

Comment: Since I consider UTC (denoted by the trailing `Z`) rather an offset then a time zone, I’d prefer the `OffsetDateTime` class. Code will be the same otherwise. If the offset is required to be `Z` always, you may even use `Instant`, though the code is different: `dtf.parse(x, Instant::from)`.

Comment: @OleV.V. Thanks, I intended to use `Instant` in my solution, but couldn't figure out a way to easily parse it from a `DateTimeFormatter`.

Answer (score 2):

You have to put quotes around the string literals that should not be interpreted:

```java
formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd'T'HHmmss'Z'");
```

Also consider that `Z` has a special parsing meaning (https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html). So if you actually want to include a timezone, you need to specify it in the input in RFC-822 format.

```
SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd'T'HHmmssZ");                                      
Date d = formatter.parse("20200926T221447-0800");
System.out.println(d);
```

Use `X` instead if your timezone is ISO8601 like your example:

Example (which I think is what you want):

```java
SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd'T'HHmmssX");
Date d = formatter.parse("20200926T221447Z");                                                                 
System.out.println(d);
```

Comment: Don't be encouraging using `Date`.  Use should use the classes from `java.time`

Comment: @WJS Thanks for the responses - much appreciated